# Modifying Custom list template type once the list is created

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-library

I have a document set library which is created using custom list template, we have given list template type as 10050 in xml and everything is working , now i have an requirement to modify the type to standard type i.e 101 for one of the third party software to work.

1. Can anyone tell me whether we can change it using powershell or so?
2. If we modify whether it will have impact on existing library?
   Existing library has ContentTypes,event receivers attached and lots
   of data and its live.

Any suggestions asap are appreciated 
:).

Answer (score 0):

Any changes on the list template will not affect your existing libraries. The changes will be in effect, when you try to create a new library out of it.

Any changes to existing libraries has be handled individually, using either server side APIs in Console application or PowerShell scripts.

Comment: How can we modify list template type of already create list .do you have any sample powershell?

Comment: You can simply write a Powershell script to upload the stp file (your list template) to catalogs\lt folder and overwrite if already exists.

Comment: I donot want to modify the list template, i want to modify the existing list's template type so that it shows standard template type.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: Oh :( so there is no way if list1 created using custom list template defined type as 10052 can be modified back as 101 for only that list.

Comment: I have the same wish... did anyone find a way? I need to change the base template to 101

Comment: Same wish here to revert to a standard 101 type. Did anyone succeed?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

- Switch the type in the code and redeploy.
- Then, run the below code snippet:

  ```
  UPDATE [content_database_name].[dbo].[AllLists] Set tp_ServerTemplate = 10000 WHERE tp_ID = 'listguid'
  ```

Comment: It deleted some of that...that should have UPDATE [content_database_name].... and tp_ID='list_guid'

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. Download template file, change extension to .cab, extract manifest.xml, change template type, use makecab to create .cab file, change extension back to template and upload it again. If error appears while using template to create new list, you have to create new list (not from template) with type you wanted to apply to existing one, then use feature id and template type from manifest.xml from newly created template file and put them to manifest.xml template you want to modify.